# setContentProtection is not hiding electron app's content in from Mac OS chrome

Tags: electron

I have been using the setContentProtection API from Electron's BrowerWindow to protect my electron app's content from screenshares. This works well in Windows. However, in MacOS, when there is a screen share happening from Google chrome, the screen capturer has access to my app's content.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known electron bug - https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/19880

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30470177)